# MS Access: data provider failed while executing a provider command

Tags: database, ms-access, oledb, database-migration, adodb

I have a database with several forms, tables and a bunch of vba code, that is has been working fine for years on Win7 and Office 2010 32bit. Basically it is a list of customers, where users can add/edit comments in textboxes, add/change status in a listbox, etc. Now when migrating to Win10 and Office 2016 32bit, the provider error comes up when I try to do anything that requires updating the recordsets. The part that generates the error is cmd.Execute in the following code:

```
Function ConnectDatabase()
On Error GoTo err

   Set dbConnection = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
Exit Function
err:
MsgBox (err.Description)
End Function

Public Sub executeAdodbCommand(sql As String, Optional cmd As ADODB.Command)
On Error GoTo err

If ADODB_Connected_OLE_DB(dbConnection) = False Then
    ConnectDatabase
End If

If cmd Is Nothing Then
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
End If

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = dbConnection
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = sql
End With

cmd.Execute

Set cmd = Nothing

Exit Sub
err:
MsgBox (err.Description)
End Sub
```

Anything I do on the forms generates error: data provider failed while executing a provider command. I have used Debug.Print to check that dbConnection.State is adStateOpen, .Provider is Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0 , .Properties("Data provider") is Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, err.source is "MSDataShape". Also, I have tested the program on my personal laptop with Win10 and Office 2016 64-bit and it worked like charm. I have checked Tools - References and they are the same on all 3 machines. I can only conclude this is a driver not a coding issue yet I have no idea what is missing and couldn't find any solutions googling the error. Maybe you guys have ideas to get it running on my work laptop? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `CurrentProject.AccessConnection`? `CurrentProject.Connection` is the preferred way for ADODB connections to Access itself, `CurrentProject.AccessConnection` has only very limited uses when creating recordsets used as record source for forms as far as I know

Comment: Yes it is an Access database only connecting to its own tables and all recordsets are used for forms, and it has always worked just fine. Anyway, I tried replacing it with CurrentProject.Connection now and this time it caused a different error now: '-2147024882 (8007000e)': Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

Comment: I think with one of those providers (ACE?) you have to make sure the previous one is uninstalled first. (I just went through this with something but I forget what is was right now. I could be off the mark here. The runtime?) You might check that there are no dups, and possibly uninstall/reinstall as needed.